# duplicate dropdown values on form post

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form in which there is a dropdown list. this list is populated with values from the database. But, when I submit the form, the dropdown list gets duplicate values.

code -

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">             

    <select name="test">
    <?php
        GetList();
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />

</form>
```

my `GetList` function -

```
function GetList()
{   
     global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT id,text FROM table"; 

    $result = mysql_query ($sql);


    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   //Array or records stored in $nt 
    echo '<option value='.$nt[id].'>'.$nt[text].'</option>'; 
    }

}
```

The dropdown list should be populated only once. I dont mind if the dropdown list is re-populated on form post but I dont want duplicate values in my dropdown list?

How do I get rid of the duplicate values?

edit - 
For e.g - if the dropdown displays values 1,2,3,4 when I first land on the page. After, i click submit, the dropdown list displays 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4. And goes on that way as many times as I submit.

Comment: Sure your query isn't getting duplicates? The code you posted should not be producing duplicates. How are you liking the transition away from .net?

Comment: I am sure my query isn't producing duplicate values. ha ha I am honestly stumped, how would you know I just moved to php? Are my questions that obvious? The transition is frustrating, I spend lot of time on simple things not because I dont know how to do it, but because I dont know how to do it using php :)

Comment: I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find any solution. I am planning to strip the entire code off and redo the page, making sure I don't make any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's either duplicate data in your database, or your loop's logic makes it go twice somehow when you do a post.  If you show the rest of your GetList code it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: I am not fetching duplicate data from the database. And, I added the rest of GetList code, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are fetching duplicate values from the database? .. or looping twice which is of course easier to spot.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not fetching duplicate values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty far-fetched guess. Does it help if you add this after your while loop:

```
mysql_free_result($result);
```